# Initializing useContext Types for Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have difficulties figuring out which types are required in order to make my custom hook work with useContext. I feel like I have tried every possible combination, but it's like a game of 'whack a mole', as soon as I get one part working another breaks.

What I find especially strange is that I get the message: `Property 'createFlow' does not exist on type 'APIProps | null'`, although it's clearly part of APIProps right? My guess is that this is because of the initialization of the context, could someone help me with this?

Thanks!

The code is relatively short, so I'll post everything for easy copy-paste testing:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext, FC } from "react";

interface APIProps {
  project?: {};
  setProject?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{}>>;
  createProject?: (project: {}) => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>;
  createFlow?: (
    projectId: string,
    patchData: {
      op: string;
      flow: {
        name: string;
        description: string;
      };
    }
  ) => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>;
}

const DBContext = createContext<APIProps | null>(null); // what to put here

export const useAPI = () => useContext(DBContext);

const DBProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [project, setProject] = useState({});

  /**
   * creates new project entry in the db, returns projectId on success
   * @param {*} project object with name, description, provider
   */
  const createProject = (project: { name: string; description: string }) =>
    axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/projects`, project);

  const createFlow = (
    projectId: string,
    patchData: { op: string; flow: { name: string; description: string } }
  ) => axios.patch(`http://localhost:3000/projects/${projectId}`, patchData);

  const value = { project, setProject, createProject, createFlow };

  return <DBContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</DBContext.Provider>;
};

export default DBProvider;
```

```
const MyComponent:FC<Props> = ({props}) => {
   // I can't figure out how to get this part to work!
   // Property 'createFlow' does not exist on type 'APIProps | null'
   const { createFlow }: APIProps | null = useAPI();

   return
     <button onClick={
         () => createFlow("id", {op: "", flow: {name: "", description: ""}})
     }>Click</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createFlow` does not exist on `null`, and you declare your type to be nullable. You have to assert that your context value is not null before using it:

```js
const MyComponent: FC<Props> = ({ props }) => {
  // I can't figure out how to get this part to work!
  // Property 'createFlow' does not exist on type 'APIProps | null'
  const api = useAPI();

  return api && <button
    onClick={() =>
      api.createFlow("id", { op: "", flow: { name: "", description: "" } })
    }
  >
    Click
  </button>;
};
```

Comment: Hey Chris, Thanks that works! Do you recommend this or is there a cleaner way to create this hook/types?

Comment: That works, or you can initialize the context with a default value which conforms to your desired non-null type (even if you just throw it away immediately when you set the context in the provider).